# How to create a FFMPEG VIDSTAB batch script Windows

Tags: windows, batch-file, video, ffmpeg

i'm a photographer and I download photographs (.jpg) and videos (.mov) into a single Windows folder

I'm looking to create a script that will run the below 3 lines of FFMPEG for every instance of .mov in the folder and let it create *stabilized* .mp4 copies of the video. I'll delete the originals manually later.

```
ffmpeg -i DSCF0229.MOV -vf vidstabdetect=shakiness=5:accuracy=15:stepsize=6:mincontrast=0.3:show=2 -y dummy.mp4

ffmpeg -i DSCF0229.MOV -vf scale=trunc((iw*1.15)/2)*2:trunc(ow/a/2)*2 -y scaled.mp4

ffmpeg -i scaled.mp4 -vf vidstabtransform=smoothing=30:input="transforms.trf":interpol=linear:crop=black:zoom=0:optzoom=1,unsharp=5:5:0.8:3:3:0.4 -y DSCF0229stabilized.mp4
```

i can tweak a bit of code, but i'm clueless on where to start. i tried "for do" and even a batch.bat file, but i just can't get the proper syntax right.

really appreciate any help here!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To perform this task you'd generally need to use a [for-loop](/questions/tagged/for-loop). To find out how to use one, use the built-in help and usage information for the command by opening up a Command Prompt window and entering `for /?`

Here's an example using a basic loop, with your [batch-file](/questions/tagged/batch-file) located in the same directory as your `.mov` files:

```bat
@For %%A In (*.mov)Do @(
    ffmpeg -i "%%A" -vf vidstabdetect=shakiness=5:accuracy=15:stepsize=6:mincontrast=0.3:show=2 -y "dummy.mp4"
    ffmpeg -i "%%A" -vf scale=trunc((iw*1.15^)/2^)*2:trunc(ow/a/2^)*2 -y "scaled.mp4"
    ffmpeg -i "scaled.mp4" -vf vidstabtransform=smoothing=30:input="transforms.trf":interpol=linear:crop=black:zoom=0:optzoom=1,unsharp=5:5:0.8:3:3:0.4 -y "%%~nAstabilized.mp4"
)
```

*You'll notice that as the `ffmpeg` commands are within a parenthesized block, that I have escaped each closing parenthesis in those command lines, (using a caret **`^`**), to prevent the `do` block from closing prematurely.*

The code above assumes that `ffmpeg.exe` is along side the batch file in the current directory, located somewhere within `%PATH%`, or has a registry entry allowing it to be run irrespective of requiring a full path. If not, you'll need to prepend the executable with that path.

Comment: HI! THANK YOU SO MUCH. THIS WORKS! 

yes i have the ffmpeg.exe file in the same folder (just gotta move it around.) this code works great already as it is. automation of my workflow!

my previous batch.bat file did not have the @ sign in front of the (. and so somehow the script created dummy.mp4 3 times and it quit after that.

Answer (score 3):

As for the `ffmpeg` part of the question:

```
ffmpeg -y -i DSCF0229.MOV -vf vidstabdetect=shakiness=5:accuracy=15:stepsize=6:mincontrast=0.3:show=2 -an -f null -
ffmpeg -i DSCF0229.MOV -vf vidstabtransform=smoothing=30:input="transforms.trf":interpol=linear:crop=black:zoom=0:optzoom=1,unsharp=5:5:0.8:3:3:0.4 -c:a copy DSCF0229stabilized.mp4
```

- No need to output a video for the first command unless you really want to see the fields and transforms. Skipping that will save time. Added `-an` to avoid audio processing because there is no need to do so for the first command.
- I see no reason for the 15% upscaling, so skip it. That step causes unnecessary generation loss because it is re-encoding needlessly. If you really wanted to upscale then just add the scale filter after the unsharp filter and you'll avoid the generation loss.
- Assuming the input audio is already AAC you can stream copy it (`-c:a copy`) and avoid re-encoding it.

Comment: Wow thanks for the ffmpeg tips as well!! I have yet to tweak that part and i will do so now with your advice!! Thank you!!